# how to hide liferay version and type to prevent hacking

Tags: liferay, version

Liferay shows its type and version when `/documents/` are used as URI:

```
http://mydomainname.zzz/documents/

/documents/  
Name    Modified    Size    Description  
redele/     -   0  
Liferay Portal Community Edition / 6.0.6
```

How can I hide that info to hackers?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Not sure if [adding friendly URL mapping](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/adding-friendly-url-mapping-to-the-portlet) helps..

Answer (score 1):

I've checked with Liferay 6.1 (EE), there this information is not given (so you might want to upgrade to the latest version, 6.1 (CE or EE).

Also there's a setting that you can change in portal-ext.properties that you might want to change. This is the default:

```
#
# Set the level of verbosity to use in the server information line printed
# by the web server servlet. Valid values are "full", which gives all of the
# version information (e.g. Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.0 CE etc.)
# or "partial", which gives only the name portion (e.g. Liferay Portal
# Community Edition).
#
web.server.servlet.version.verbosity=full
```

However, the main recommendation for security is to stay on the latest version and always fix it. If you don't want to upgrade when the next major CE version is released: EE is supported for 5 years (if this statement is considered marketing and not ok here, feel free to delete it)